# Python - Access column based on another column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe in python

```
+-------+--------+
| Value | Number |
+-------+--------+
| true  |    123 |
| false |    234 |
| true  |    345 |
| true  |    456 |
| false |    567 |
| false |    678 |
| false |    789 |
+-------+--------+
```

How do I conduct an operation which returns a list of all the 'Number' which has Value == TRUE

The output list expected from the above table is

```
['123', '345', '456']
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.loc[df['Value'],'Number']` should work assuming the dtype for 'Value' are real booleans:

```
In [68]:
df.loc[df['Value'],'Number']

Out[68]:
0    123
2    345
3    456
Name: Number, dtype: int64
```

The above uses boolean indexing, here the boolean values are a mask against the df.

If you want a `list`:

```
In [69]:
df.loc[df['Value'],'Number'].tolist()

Out[69]:
[123, 345, 456]
```

Comment: @JonClements sure if the dtype is `str` but it's unclear from the OP as it looks like `str` but then in the question they compare against `TRUE` which is equally baffling

Comment: @EdChum, it is a boolean list and this works like a charm! Thank you!